# Ruby on Rails: Error `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to set up redmine on an managed server. Redmine installation works, I can start the rails server and visit the redmine page localy with lynx.
Integration in the Apache is done via FCGI and when I enter the redmine start page in my browser I get an Server error 500. In the server logs I see this:

```
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/startup.rb:1:in `<main>'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
Feb 18 01:17:12 dedi444 apache:         from /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/startup.rb:1:in `<main>'
Feb 18 01:17:18 dedi444 apache: [Tue Feb 18 01:17:18.386071 2020] [fcgid:info] [pid 31847:tid 140048663593024] mod_fcgid: process /usr/www/users/admin/test/dispatch.fcgi(3096) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 1
```

I searched for the errormessage other answers recommended an **bundle install** - output is

```
...
Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 58 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development, test and rmagick were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `/usr/home/admin/.gem`
```

**EDIT**
additional info: I continued searching for answers, maybe the GEM_PATH is the problem and ruby can't find the bundle/setup. 
My fcgi script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/dash                                                                                                                                       
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/"
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME:/var/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
exec /usr/bin/ruby /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/startup.rb
```

How can I find the location of the 'bundle/setup' on my system?

Any idea what I can do?

Thanks a lot
Klaus

Answer (score 1):

Looks that you have ambiguity with your ruby & gem paths. 
They are installed  in `/usr/home/admin/.gem` and fcgi is trying to find them in `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/` that's because Apache doesn't know where to look.

You should try passing env config variables via **.htaccess** file if your shared hosting system allows it or via apache config

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/home/admin/.gem
```

However, Redmine is preferably used via some application server *(puma, thin, webrick...)*, and reverse-proxied or run via Passenger as Apache module, and preferably it uses Ruby installed via rvm or rbenv...

Thus, depending upon version, it might also require you to add

`gem "fcgi"`  in `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` again, and also to add these lines in `dispatch.fcgi`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fcgi'
```